# Mistake with Django template localization

Tags: python, django, localization

I have problem with localization. My site has english and russian locales. From start  a label "Home" was translated to russian, but i didn't add a django.po file, but now i add and translate do not work.

Part from django.po, as you see I did not changed "Home" label, but it translated...

```
#: templates/base.html:7 templates/base.html.py:96 templates/login.html:15
msgid "Friends on Map"
msgstr "Друзья на карте"

#: templates/base.html:100 templates/login.html:10
msgid "Home"
msgstr ""
```

I tried add a folder "local" to different project folder but it did not help.

Picture like it see

[image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/q06tvioz849dy19/Screenshot%20from%202013-11-26%2003%3A30%3A09.png]

And project structure

[image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/fa0d2iry41m8coh/Screenshot%20from%202013-11-26%2003%3A35%3A09.png]

**UPDATE** 01.12
This is my base.html:

```
{% load static %}
{% load i18n %}
<!Doctype html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>{% trans "Friends on Map" %}</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="/static/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="/static/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <script language="JavaScript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    {% block mapJS %}
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=key&sensor=false">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.maps.visualRefresh = true;
        var map;
        function initialize() {

                var mapOptions = {
                    zoom: 3,
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(0,0),
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
                };

                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
                        mapOptions);

                {% if backends.associated %}
                    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng({{ user_model.extra_data.user_info.current_location.latitude }},
                                {{ user_model.extra_data.user_info.current_location.longitude }}
                    );

                    addMarker("{{ user_model.extra_data.user_info.current_location.latitude }}",
                            "{{ user_model.extra_data.user_info.current_location.longitude }}",
                            "{{ user_model.extra_data.user_info.name }}",
                            "{{ user_model.extra_data.user_info.current_location.name }}",
                            "{{ user_model.extra_data.user_info.pic_big }}");

                    var json1 = {{ friends|safe }};
                    $.each(json1, function(key, data){
                    addMarker(data.current_location.latitude,
                        data.current_location.longitude,
                        data.name,
                        data.current_location.name,
                        data.pic_square);
                        console.log(data.name);
                    });
                {% endif %}
        }

        function addMarker(lat,lng,name,address,photo) {

             var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
                  '<div id="siteNotice">'+
                  '</div>'+
                  '<p>'+ name +'</p>'+
                  '<div id="bodyContent">'+
                  '<img src="'+ photo +'">'+
                  '<p>'+ address +'</p>'+
{#                  '<href="'+ url+ '">'+#}
                  '</div>'+
                  '</div>';

             var Marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
                    title: name,
             });

             var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: contentString
             });

             google.maps.event.addListener(Marker, 'click', function() {
                 infowindow.open(map,this);

             });

             Marker.setMap(map);
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
    {% endblock %}
{#    {% block scripts %}{% endblock %}#}
    {% block head_scripts %}{% endblock %}
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="/login">{% trans "Friends on Map" %}</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="/login">{% trans "Home" %}</a></li>
            <li><a href="/about">{% trans "About" %}</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-right"><!-- Set language start -->
            <form action="/i18n/setlang/" class="active" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ redirect_to }}" />
            {% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}
            {% for language in languages %}
            <input name="language" type="submit" value="{{ language.code }}"/>
            {% endfor %}
            </form>
          </ul><!-- Set language end-->
        </div><!-- /.nav-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container -->
    </div><!-- /.navbar -->

     <div class="container">

      <div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-right">

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
           <div class="jumbotron">
               {% block content %}
            <div id="map-canvas"></div>
           </div>
                {% endblock %}
        </div>

     <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 sidebar-offcanvas" id="sidebar" role="navigation">
        <div class="well sidebar-nav">
          <div class="list-group">
            {% block sidebar %}{% endblock %}
          </div>
        </div><!--/span-->
      </div>




    <form method="post" action="" id="disconnect-form">{% csrf_token %}</form>
    <script src="/static/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function () {
          $(document).on('click', 'a.disconnect', function (e) {
              e.preventDefault();
              $('form#disconnect-form')
                  .attr('action', $(this).attr('href'))
                  .submit();
          });
      });
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is your problem that `friends on map` is **not** translated, or that `Home` **is** translated? If first, can you provide your template excerpt, part with navbar definition.

Comment: Only 'Home' translated, yes, I'll provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django have a built in translation for many languages and they get kicked in for many keywords.
See possible solutions at: [How do I disable default translation values in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9961411/how-do-i-disable-default-translation-values-in-django)